# If intermediate certificate has expiry date after root certificate, does it throw any error with openssl?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, libressl

If intermediate certificate has expiry date after root certificate, does it throw any error with openssl?
I recently encountered openssl `error 7 : X509_V_ERR_CERT_SIGNATURE_FAILURE` with cert chain . I wonder if above question could cause this issue as intermediate cert had expiry after root.

Answer (score 0):

could ask for the updated intermediate certificate to your provider or could you remove the intermediate certificate from your crt. files. (i recommend first option first). In my case was sectigo company. Follow instructions for this link to get updated certificates https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000rfBO